# Flutter: How to change Tab's icon's color on SLIDE, not just on tap?

Tags: flutter, tabs, tabbar

So, I have set up a TabBarView with its tabs containing an icon and text each.
The text seem to linearly change color as you switch between tabs by sliding. How do you achieve this same effect for the icon as well? I managed to make it switch color ON TAP but it's not obeying the same rule when sliding.

I have tried with `tabController.index == 0` etc. Still not working.

Answer (score 2):

Work With `Tap` Or `Sliding` Both :

```
child: new TabBar(
                  indicatorColor: Colors.white,
                  unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey, // for unselected
                  labelColor: Colors.white, // for selected
                  indicatorWeight: 5.0,
                  tabs: [
                    new Tab(
                      text: 'Unpaid'.toUpperCase(),
                    ),
                    new Tab(
                      text: 'Draft'.toUpperCase(),
                    ),
                    new Tab(
                      text: 'All'.toUpperCase(),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            body: new TabBarView(
              children: [
                new first.UnpaidInvoicePage(),
                new second.PaidInvoicePage(),
                new third.AllInvoicePage(),
              ],
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please Try below code:**

- labelColor: Colors.black, // Selected Tab Color(icon,text)
- unselectedLabelColor: Colors.amber, // Unselected Tab Color(icon,text)

========================================================================

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(TabBarDemo());
}

class TabBarDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 3,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            bottom: TabBar(
              unselectedLabelColor: Colors.amber, // UnSelected Tab Color
              labelColor: Colors.black, // Selected Tab Color
              tabs: [
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_car)),
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_transit)),
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_bike)),
              ],
            ),
            title: Text('Tabs Demo'),
          ),
          body: TabBarView(
            children: [
              Icon(Icons.directions_car),
              Icon(Icons.directions_transit),
              Icon(Icons.directions_bike),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```